# I have a DataTable. I want to print it on Maui. How can I do that? Or something similar to wpf's DataGrid

Tags: c#, maui, .net-maui, maui-windows

**I have a DataTable. I want to print it to the interface Maui. How can I do that?**

---

In WPF I did it like this on C#:

```
gridPrinted.ItemsSource = myclass.GetDataTable().AsDataView();
```

WPF XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gridPrinted" Grid.Row="1" LoadingRow="gridPrinted_LoadingRow" CanUserAddRows="False"/>
```

---

In Maui, I have been trying to use CollectionView like this:

C# code:

```
DataView dat = myclass.GetDataTable().AsDataView();
```

XAML code:

```
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding dat}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                Text="{Binding label}"
                                FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

However nothing happens. No table is generated, but also no errors, no exceptions, nothing.
How can I print that table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We couldn't see the other code of  your app, but you can try to check the following aspects:

1.`DataView dat = myclass.GetDataTable().AsDataView();`

Here, the returned type of `myclass.GetDataTable().AsDataView()` should be a list,for example:

```
public ObservableCollection<YourItem>  items;
```

or

```
 System.Collections.Generic.IList<YourItem> items;
```

2.make sure set the `BindingContext` for your page;

3.make sure there is a returned value  for the `ItemsSource` of  your CollectionView.

```
  myclass.GetDataTable().AsDataView();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have created an IEnumerable type using the rows and managed to make a vertical list with as many items as there are rows, which means I can make a table with a dynamical number of lines. However, I have been struggling to make it have a dynamical number of columns. I can print one column of the table or two using Labels, and binding them to the vector position of the row, but nothing dynamical. I have made another question for this. Do you have any suggestion?